# Omnisharp 1.25.7 and VScode formatting error .razor files

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, razor-pages, apple-m1, omnisharp

On my mac m1, when I try to auto format .razor files, Omnisharp throws the following error:

[Error - 16:20:32] Request textDocument/formatting failed.
Message: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. (Parameter 'Range end line 25 matches or exceeds SourceText boundary 25.')
Code: -32000
[object Object]

With .cs files everything works as expected. I have already tried to reinstall VScode. Downgrading Omnisharp to 1.25.2 works, but then the formatting is broken ( Html indentation is not correct ). Does anyone have a solution for this? Thanks in advance! This drives me crazy...

```
    @foreach (var prodGroup in groupedProductsByCategory)
    {
      <div class="row mt-3">
  <h4>
    @prodGroup.FirstOrDefault(pg => pg.CategoryId ==
    prodGroup.Key)?.CategoryName
  </h4>
  <DisplayProducts Products="@prodGroup"></DisplayProducts>
</div>
      <hr class="mb-3" />
    }
```

What I have tried:

- Downgrading Omnisharp
- Reinstalling VSCode
- Reinstalling all extensions
- Changing lots of settings

Comment: It's a [bug in Omnisharp](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5561#issuecomment-1534228903). You can try downgrading to [v1.25.3](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/releases/tag/v1.25.3) as someone triaged it to [1.25.4](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5561#issuecomment-1405833747). [The fix](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5561#issuecomment-1534228903) is supposed to be shipped soon(TM).

Comment: Thx for your answer!! In VScode I can only downgrade to 1.25.2... Is there a way to downgrade manually ?

Comment: 1.25.2 should be fine, you can install arbitrary release by following [steps in official documentation](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Installing-Beta-Releases) if you want 1.25.3 specifically.

Comment: Yes, but on 1.25.2 my html indentation after formatting in the razor file is not correct :/.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.